# What are the possible values of "status" in the SonarQube WebApi /api/ce/task call?

Tags: sonarqube

I’m using SonarQube 7.9.2.

I have some automation that calls the /api/ce/task WebApi endpoint. It needs to check the “status” property. In my initial testing, I found that a value of “IN_PROGRESS” means that the task isn’t complete yet. As the doc doesn’t SAY what the possible values are, I guessed that this is the value that means the task isn’t done yet. Today I saw that this code wasn’t working properly in some cases, and that was because instead of “IN_PROGRESS”, I was getting “PENDING”.

As the WebApi docs only give “response examples” instead of providing something resembling a schema, can someone tell me what the actual possible values are for this property, and their meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four possible values:

1. **SUCCESS:** When the sonar analysis is completed and execution is success.
2. **ERROR:** When the sonar analysis is completed but execution is failed.
3. **PENDING:** When the analysis is completed but the report is in queued and waiting to be processed on the server side.
4. **IN_PROGRESS:** When the analysis is completed, but the report has reached the head of the queue and is being integrated in server side.
   Depending on the size of the project and the resources available to the server this could happen very quickly or take a few minutes.